# Pikachoose compatibility with Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox, pikachoose

I'm trying to use Pikachoose (an image slider) along with Colorbox (alternative to lightbox, which I had the same issue on), however whenever I click on the image (not the thumbnail), the image opens in a whole new window. Pikachoose is working as expected.

I've followed the "Usage" page exactly, and checked mine against the examples code, and they're identical except for the links between images. You can see I've got a separate image outside of the `<div class='pikachoose'>` tag, which works as expected.

Does anybody know how to make the two compatible?

Here is the code I've used. I've omitted the `<link>` and `<script>` tags to save space as I know I've got them correct.

```
<head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pikachoose">
    <ul id="pikame">
    <!-- to override thumbnails use <img src="thumbnail.jpg" ref="fullsize.jpg"> -->
        <li><a class="group1" href="images/image1.png"><img src="images/image1.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a class="group1" href="images/image2.png"><img src="images/image2.png"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a class="group1" href="images/image1.png"><img src="images/image2.png"/></a>

<script>
    jQuery('a.group1').colorbox();
</script>
</body>
```

Alternate question: Does anybody know any gallery plugins that are very low key, that have colorbox/lightbox functionality? Akin to Amazon, Ebay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to make the two compatible, and went on to creating my own instead. I tried to keep it as lightweight as possible while still looking nice and functioning well.

As many experienced in jQuery (even if only moderately), can probably tell I'm still learning - any comments/fixes etc would be greatly appreciated.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mraxlee/bmu43fm7/8/)

Automatic cycling doesn't seem to work on JSFiddle but is working fine when on my site. For some reason the first image won't load into lightbox until you click the thumb first - <s>again this is just a JSFiddle problem</s> This seemed to be a mishap in my PHP version that I wrote, however I can't seem to find the actual cause of this. I'm guessing it's due to me printing out the main image wrong the first time, but letting the jQuery patch it up. If somebody could let me know what caused this I'd be greatful as I can't see. To fix it, I just called `$('.thumb:first').click();` at the very end to simulate clicking the first thumb. It styles slightly differently on JSFiddle than it does usually, but it still works.

It uses very simple HTML - basic image and link tags, there's not really much to say about it.

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id='image'>
        <a href='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=1' data-lightbox='image-1' data-title='test1'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=1' border='0' class='image'/></a>
    </div>

    <div id='thumbs'>
        <a href='#' rel='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=1' data-ligtbox='image-1' data-title='test1' class='image'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=1' class='thumb active' border='0'/></a>
        <a href='#' rel='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=2' data-title='test2' class='image'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=2' class='thumb' border='0'/></a>
        <a href='#' rel='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=3' data-title='test3' class='image'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=3' class='thumb' border='0'/></a>
        <a href='#' rel='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=4' data-title='test4' class='image'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=4' class='thumb' border='0'/></a>
        <a href='#' rel='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=5' data-title='test5' class='image'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=5' class='thumb' border='0'/></a>
        <a href='#' rel='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=6' data-title='test6' class='image'><img src='http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=6' class='thumb' border='0'/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some very simple CSS

```
#image {
    padding:5px;
    float: left;
}
#thumbs {
    float:left;
    width: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
.thumb {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.active {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

Noted javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //setting the timer for automatic cycling as a variable
    var timer = setInterval('CycleImages()', 5000);
    //checking if the user is hovering over the slider
    $('#slider').hover(function(ev){
        //cancels the timer if the user is hovering
    clearInterval(timer);
    }, function(ev){
        //calls the timer if the user is not hovering
    timer = setInterval('CycleImages()', 5000);
    });
    //clicking thumbnails
    $(".image").click(function() {
        var image = $(this).attr("rel"); //getting the rel tag from the a tag
        var title = $(this).attr("data-title"); //data title from a tag
        $('#image').fadeOut('fast', function() { //fades out last image
            $('#image').html('<a href="' + image + '" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="' + title + '"><img src="' + image + '" class="image"/></a>'); //HTML for the new image
            $('#image').fadeIn('fast'); //fades in the new image
        });
        $('#image').html('<a href="' + image + '" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="' + title + '"><img src="' + image + '" class="image"/></a>'); //HTML for the new image
        $(this).siblings().find('img').removeClass('active'); //removes active class from old thumbnail
        $(this).find('img').addClass('active'); //adds the active class to the new active thumbnail
        return false;
    });
    $('.thumb:first').click();
});

function CycleImages(){
//if there is another thumbnail img after currently selected
    if($('.active').parent().next().find('img').length > 0) {
        //simulate clicking the next thumbnail
        $('.active').parent().next().find('img').click();
    } else {
        //if there is only one image
        if($('.thumb:first').parent().next().find('img').length == 0 ) {
            return;
        } else {
        //if not simulate clicking the first thumbnail
        $('.thumb:first').click();
        }
    }
}
```

I used PHP for mine, to pull the images from an array - I thought this would be easier to add more images to (and to change images later) and in the future I plan on pulling the images from a database so this would be much easier.

```
//setting images multidimensional array
images = array(
    array("http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=1","test1"),
    array("http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=2","test2"),
    array("http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=3","test3"),
    array("http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=4","test4"),
    array("http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=5","test5"),
    array("http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000000/fff&text=6","test6"),
);
$i = 0; //counter
foreach($images as $image){ //looping images
    if($i == 0) { //if first loop
        //print out first image as the large image
        print "<div id='image'>\n<a href='".$image[0]."' data-lightbox='image-1' data-title='".$image[1]."'><img src='".$image[0]."' border='0' class='image'/></a>\n</div>";
        //start the div tag for the thumbs
        print "<div id='thumbs'>";
    }
    //print out thumb
    print "<a href='#' rel='".$image[0]."' data-title='".$image[1]."' class='image'><img src='".$image[0]."' class='thumb";
    if($i==0) { print " active"; }; //makes first thumb active
    print "' border='0'/></a>";
    $i++; //updates counter
}
print "</div>";
```